# UTM Tracking in GA4 | Firing Problem?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, wordpress, utm-parameters

I've created a few UTM links for social media tracking and have validated them as working/proper with multiple tools. That said, when I try to replicate an organic user with the UTM link on a different browser using incognito/private, I'm not able to see any data on GA4. I am in the traffic acquisition and sorting by source/medium, so I know I'm looking in the right place.

I'm conviced something on the site isn't allowing the UTMs to fire properly? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking on real-time user data First user source/medium on GA4 cause it will reflect in 48hours on acquisition > source/medium on GA4 also kindly check this tool https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/campaign-url-builder/ to create UTM